# How do I pass header values with cloud functions emulator?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

When calling an http triggered function, I can pass in request body with `--data` or `--file`, but is there a way to pass in header values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that via standard functions CLI tool.
You can try to send requests using Postman for example, which provides way more possibilities on making HTTP requests.